# AWS Cognito: User exist in the User pool but Sign in gives user not found exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am new to AWS Cognito. I have created a user in the user pool using aws cli by using the admin create user command. Then I am trying to log in using SSO, but it gives a

> user doesn't exist

message.

Command to create user:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-create-user \
    --user-pool-id POOLID \
    --username USERNAME \
    --temporary-password PASSWORD \
    --user-attributes Name=email,Value=XXX Name=phone_number,Value=XXX\
    --message-action SUPPRESS
```

URL to access cognito:

```
https://<domain_name>.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=<clientId>&response_type=code&scope=email+openid&redirect_uri=<redirect-uri>
```

Comment: Can you give us some more information, because this question does not hold enough data to know what is going on or what is going wrong. What is the specific configuration of the user pool? What user pool client are you using to log in? What is the configuration of that client etc...

Comment: Can you verify the user in userpool then try again?

Comment: Yes, It has been resolved now. the user was not verified and hence was not allowed to log in. I checked the email_verified attribute to true and it started working. @NinadGaikwad